# Multiple window project in c# - Updating data in Form1 from Form2

Tags: c#, winforms

First I will outline the logic of my project so you know what I'm trying to achieve.

- I have `Form1` which is the main form.
- I have `Form2` which is opened when a button is clicked in `Form1`
- I have a class `Student` which contains some properties (name, id, bday) which are all private but have getters and setters

`Student` can be instantiated by

`Student s = new Student(name, int, bday);`

- I have a class `University` which has a property `List<Student>` which as you might imagine, contains a list of `Students`

Now how my program is *meant* to work is ..

- `Form1` displays the list of students
- `Form2` creates the students, and adds them to the `studentList` in `Form1` when a button is clicked. `Form2` also closes when this same button is clicked

What I was thinking I could do is have a "global" list in `University` and `Form2` updates this "global" list, then `Form1` displays this "global" list.

This is what `Form1` looks like

[image]

And this is what `Form2` looks like

[image]

I'm looking for ideas on how I can achieve this, here is some code from each `Form` that might help

`Form1`

```
    private static List<Student> studentListHome;
    University mainUniversity = new University(studentListHome);

    public List<Student> StudentListHome
    {
        get
        {
            return studentListHome;
        }
        set
        {
            studentListHome = value;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(studentListHome != null)
        {
            mainUniversity.StudentList.Concat(studentListHome).ToList();
            studentListBox.DataSource = mainUniversity.StudentList;
            studentListBox.DisplayMember = "name";
        }

    }


    private void studentToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 studentForm = new Form2();
        studentForm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

`Form2`

```
private string studentName;
private int studentID;
private string studentBDay;
private List<Student> studentListForm2 = new List<Student>();
Form1 homeForm ;

private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comparator(nameInput) &
       comparator(idInput) &
       comparator(bdayInput)){
        variable_assignment();
        var tempStudent = StudentCreation();
        if(tempStudent != null)
        {
            studentListForm2.Add(tempStudent);
        }
        homeForm.StudentListHome = studentListForm2;
        Close();

    }
}
```

In `Form2` `comparator` is a function that returns a bool, it checks to make sure that the input fields aren't empty.

`variable_assignment` takes the user input and assigns it to the relative variable (`studentName`, `studentID`, `studentBDay`)

`StudentCreation()` is a function that returns a `Student` it simply instantiates a `Student` using the new values of `studentName` `studentID` `studentBDay` and in my case, is assigned to `tempStudent`

As my code is now, when I run it, I get an error 
`An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in TestProjectForProject5.exe`

and it references this line of code

`homeForm.StudentListHome = studentListForm2;`

I'm guessing this is because homeForm is never instantiated. I have done this because I don't know how to reference this current `Form1` that is open, I do not want to create a new `Form1` and send data to it, I want to send data to the original `Form1`.

So my question is, how do I fix this error, and be able to send data to the original `Form1` like I'm intending to do, not a new `Form1`

Comment: How about storing the information on a table or any temporary container, then getting that information on your 2nd form instead? Or, make use of `TCP/IP` listener objects?

Answer (score 0):

your getting this error because your homeForm is null.

create a constructor in form 2 and pass parameter of form1 , something like in form2 :

```
 public Form2(From1 frm1)
   {
   homeForm =frm1;
   }

 private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     //your code 
     homeForm.StudentListHome = studentListForm2;
     homeForm.BindData();
     Close();
   }
```

Then Pass the object of form1,something like in form 1:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   BindData();
  }
  Public Void BindData()
   {
      if(studentListHome != null)
       {
          mainUniversity.StudentList.Concat(studentListHome).ToList();
          studentListBox.DataSource = mainUniversity.StudentList;
          studentListBox.DisplayMember = "name";
        }
    }

   private void studentToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Form2 studentForm = new Form2(this);
      studentForm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: `mainUniversity.StudentList.Concat(studentListHome).ToList();` This line says there is a null exception error

Comment: try debugging to find when its changing to null...I think u have make mainUniversity.StudentList object as static.. can u post University class code